# TypeError: interpolate is not a function after installing react-nativgation-drawer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer

**I am learning react native and during this i was trying to implement drawer navigation but as soon as i installed the react-navigation-drawer(2.2.0) this error pops up.**

Behaviour :
App crash on load

Reproduce :
Just reload the app

Package.js

```
{
      "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "web": "expo start --web",
        "eject": "expo eject"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "expo": "~42.0.1",
        "expo-app-loading": "^1.1.2",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
        "react": "16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "16.13.1",
        "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
        "react-native-screens": "^3.4.0",
        "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
        "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
        "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.7.1",
        "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
      },
      "private": true
    }
```

App.js

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading  from 'expo-app-loading';
//import Navigator from './routes/homestack'
import Navigator from './routes/drawernav';




const loadFont = ()=>Font.loadAsync({
    'merrie-regular':require('./assets/fonts/Merriweather-Regular.ttf'),
    'merrie-bold':require('./assets/fonts/Merriweather-Bold.ttf')
  });

export default function App() {
  const [isFontLoaded,setFontLoaded] = useState(false);
  if(isFontLoaded){
    return (
      //initial changes again
       <Navigator/>
      
    );
  }else{ 
    return(
      
        <AppLoading
        startAsync = {loadFont}
        onFinish = {()=>setFontLoaded(true)}
        onError = {()=>alert('Error')}
        />
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
AppLoading threw an unexpected error when loading:
    TypeError: interpolate is not a function. (In 'interpolate(this.progress, {
                  inputRange: [PROGRESS_EPSILON, 1],
                  outputRange: [0, 1]
                })', 'interpolate' is undefined)     

**Already Tried:
1.Changing reanimated version
2.Uninstall and install reanimated version.
3.Uninstall and install drawer-navigation**
```

Note: It's on both android and IOS simulators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your react-navigation-drawer version is conflicting with the version of react-native-reanimated. Try to run `npm i --save react-native-reanimated@1.0.0`.

Downgrade your react-native-reanimated to version 1.1.0
Run this command in terminal
`yarn add react-native-reanimated@1.0.0`

Comment: that worked thanks alot .Although I am not sure what drawbacks it comes when we downgrade is there any doc for this comparison?

Comment: @AshutoshBhardwaj You are not using the latest version of `react-navigation-drawer` that's why you need to downgrade your reanimated library too. If you want to use the latest version then you need to upgrade your `drawer` library also. And,  there will no drawbacks of not using the latest version of any library.

Comment: Actually I started with latest drawer version 2.2.0 but then app crashed,isn't it latest